# Can you prove the Law of Large Numbers?

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

So clearly it is not hard to experimentally prove that the more times something is done, say rolling a die, the closer your experimental results come to your theoretical likelihoods, but is there a mathematical way to show why this occurs?

Thanks

Comment: the simplest version would be if $X_k$ are iid random variables with mean $\mu$, then $S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ converges (in probability and a.s.) to the constant $\mu$.  see any book on probability or start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: @user What precisely do you think the statement of the law of large numbers is? You have to formalize it before you can prove it - which the Wikipedia page mentioned above does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most proofs prove the Chebychev inequality and then use that to prove the law of large numbers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Proof_using_Chebyshev.27s_inequality